# How to test the distribution of the transcripts per million (tpm) values and analyze ASE (allele specific expression) differences between haplotypes?

Tags: r, distributions, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data

**I have the TPM (transcripts per million) values generated for my RNAseq data. My overall goal is to identify genes that show allele specific expression differences.**

In the table below the TPM values (gene.erc.M and gene.erc.S) are for two different haplotypes (flagged as M and S) and the total TPM for that locus (gene or id) is T, so reads for M+S = reads for T. **See the data table and description below for more details.**

**Here is my data structure:**

```
gene_id_locus   gene.erc.M  gene.erc.S  gene.erc.T
Al_scaffold_0001_1044   713 314 1027
Al_scaffold_0001_1048   774 483 1257
Al_scaffold_0001_1062   193 199 392
Al_scaffold_0001_1084   8   50  58
Al_scaffold_0001_1095   7   9   16
Al_scaffold_0001_1106   392 8   400
Al_scaffold_0001_1120   253 62  315
Al_scaffold_0001_1122   38  38  76
Al_scaffold_0001_1125   311 135 446
Al_scaffold_0001_1133   164 71  235
Al_scaffold_0001_1146   364 302 666
Al_scaffold_0001_1151   265 51  316
Al_scaffold_0001_1171   34  37  71
Al_scaffold_0001_1186   26  39  65
Al_scaffold_0001_1189   170 208 378
Al_scaffold_0001_1195   551 158 709
Al_scaffold_0001_1209   91  56  147
Al_scaffold_0001_1233   81  46  127
Al_scaffold_0001_1245   121 19  140
Al_scaffold_0001_125    378 153 531
Al_scaffold_0001_1271   138 95  233
Al_scaffold_0001_1275   35  150 185
Al_scaffold_0001_128    73  2115    2188
Al_scaffold_0001_1280   67  149 216
Al_scaffold_0001_1283   28  67  95
Al_scaffold_0001_1304   12  12  25
Al_scaffold_0001_1307   48  16  64
Al_scaffold_0001_1326   248 73  321
#contd.......
```

There are about 16000 gene_id (after filtering), thats why there is going to be a some good amount of over dispersion.

**Description:**

- `gene_locus_id` - is the gene name
- `gene.erc.T` - represent the total number of transcripts from the  - `corresponding gene_locus_id.` This values is different than RPKM, FPKM, so I don't have to worry about normalization any more.
- `gene.erc.M` - represent the total number of transcripts from the corresponding `gene_locus_id` but with haplotype M.
- `gene.erc.S` - same as above but for haplotype S.

**This is what I want to do specifially:**

1. Find the appropriate distribution of my data (for M, S and T); poisson vs. negative binomial? Generally data from RNAseq have over-dispersion so negative binomial regression might be appropriate, but I want to check for dispersion and distribution for the data either way?
2. If any transformation is needed? - I have tried some log transformation but I am not getting anything useful.

   [image: log of (erc.gene.M/erc.gene.S)]

   [image: gene.erc.T vs. (log(erc.M/S) * sqrt(gene.erc.T))]
3. My main goal is to see if there is significant expression differences between two haplotypes (M vs. S) for the same gene ID. - I tried looking for similar examples around but not finding anythig useful. DeSeq, edgeR mainly focus on variation between samples and condition. I tried to apply those but looks like I am having brain freeze in here.

Comment: Can someone chip in some ideas about this kind of problem?